# cannot view old ogone orders after new version installation

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I recently upgraded a magento store from 1.3.2.4 to 1.5.0.1. The 1.3.2.4 store used ogone as its payments handler. Once I upgraded magento to 1.5.0.1 I had to reinstall ogone but the previous version of ogone used Magento Connect 1.0 and the 1.5.0.1 need Magento Connect 2.0.

So, I had to install the new ogone module (that is compatible with 1.5.0.1 version of magento). The module installed successfully and I am able to process payments but the old orders are not viewable (through customer account and also admin) panel as I get an error Cannot retrieve payment method instance".

Please let me know how I can view the old orders in the system

Regards,